# What is the Dropbox iOS app's equivalent of "fb://"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, dropbox-api, deep-linking

Sorry, I can tell I don't entirely know what I'm talking about. For example, to open a URL for Facebook, the prefix is "fb://". Does anyone happen to know the prefix for Dropbox?

I'm pretty sure it has one, because in the new Dropbox API (1.0) it opens the Dropbox app from within your app to let the user log in, and the only way I know of doing this would be through one of those prefix things which I don't know what they are called.

I do not actually want to open a file in Dropbox. I actually want to detect whether Dropbox is installed on the iPhone, and the best way that I can think of to do this is with this method (shown for detecting whether the Facebook app is installed).

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://"]]) {
    NSLog(@"Facebook is installed.");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Facebook is not installed.");
}
```

If you know a better way of detecting whether this app is installed please share.

Comment: if the `"dropbox://"` prefix doesn't work yet, cast a vote for it at https://www.dropbox.com/votebox/2078/add-url-scheme-for-iphone-ipad-dropbox-app-to-drop-in-files

Comment: Yes, I tried db:// and dropbox:// and then I decided to stop guessing and ask to see if anyone else knew

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only URL scheme listed in Dropbox's Info.plist is `dbapi-1`; that should work for what you're trying to do.

Edit: Just tried it out; it works (says "installed" on my device with Dropbox and "not installed" in the simulator).

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know if it's possible to send any parameters with that scheme? To open a specified folder, for instance.

Comment: I suppose it's possible that some of the stuff at https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api might work. I haven't tried, though.

Comment: dbapi-2 now, it seems.