# Does the DropBox app on iOS have a URL scheme?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, dropbox, url-scheme

I would like to be able to launch the DropBox app within my app. Therefore I would like to know if the DropBox app has a URL scheme that I can use to call openURL, something like this, except I don't know what this string should be.

```
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"dropbox://"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:myURL];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get the URL scheme from the bundle identifier in iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405734/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-url-scheme-from-the-bundle-identifier-in-ios)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697488/what-is-the-dropbox-ios-apps-equivalent-of-fb (and Justin's answer).

Answer (score 4):

The only thing you can do with the Dropbox url-scheme is connect your Dropbox App to it.
Like this:

```
var key = "[YOUR API KEY]";
var secret = "[YOUR API SECRET]";
var apiversion = "1";

window.open("dbapi-1://"+apiversion+"/connect?k="+key+"&s="+secret);
```

Normally the dropbox-app responses by opening your iOS app with the following scheme:

```
db-[YOU API KEY]://connect?oauth_token=SOMETOKEN&oauth_token_secret=SOMEOATHTOKEN&uid=SOMETHING
```

or with:

```
db-[YOU API KEY]://cancel
```

Got this from looking at the Dropbox SDK for iOS.

Answer (score 3):

Dropbox's URL scheme is

```
dbapi-1://
```

Comment: Where did you find that, do you have a reference? When I use Google, I find different schemes and none of them standardized or official.

Comment: sourced from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697488/what-is-the-dropbox-ios-apps-equivalent-of-fb

Comment: So, it is indeed not a standard URI scheme, but application specific. But, that said, it should work once Dropbox is installed. You can edit your question to contain a link or something, then I can remove the downvote.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to open a specific file in the iOS Dropbox app, you can use this trick:

1. Encode your URL.
2. Append encoded URL to the `dbapi-6://1/viewLink?url=` prefix.

**Attention:** this is not documented and may change in future releases.

The whole code should look like this:

```
// `yourURLString` is the URL string you want to open 

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"dbapi-6://"]) 
{    
    NSString *encodedFileURLString =
        [yourURLString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSString *fullURLString = 
        [@"dbapi-6://1/viewLink?url=" stringByAppendingString:encodedFileURLString];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fullURLString]];
}
else
{
    // Otherwise open Safari
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:yourURLString]];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Dropbox does not have a URL scheme. However, you can interact with Dropbox via `UIDocumentInteractionController`. You can read about that [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010403). I've seen a few apps that allow you to open files in Dropbox, and I assume this is how that's done.

Comment: Are you sure they don't have a URL scheme?

Comment: @newenglander As of the writing of this answer they did not have an official URL scheme. However, they do seem to have an unofficial one. See Justin's answer.