# Detect if DropBox app is not installed

Tags: ios, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am building an iOS app with the Dropbox core-API for iOS. My app is not functional without Dropbox so before my app starts up, I'd like to know how to detect if the dropbox app is/isn't installed.

How do I do this?

Comment: Similar question: [How to determine if Dropbox has been installed on iOS device?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15095892/1886070)

Comment: Why do you think you need the Dropbox app installed to use the Dropbox Core API (because you don't)?

Answer (score 1):

Using the Dropbox core API the user will be able to link to the web version of Dropbox automatically without having the Dropbox app installed. Correct me if I am wrong, but making your app depend on a second app being installed may result in rejection by apple.