# Dropbox URL scheme

Tags: ios, dropbox, url-scheme

I am looking about URL scheme actions.

I found link: [Does dropbox app on iOS has a URL scheme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406546/does-dropbox-app-on-ios-has-a-url-scheme) two years old.

I don't know is new actions in dropbox as "Go to file with path" or other.

Comment: There currently isn't any URL scheme for opening a particular file in the Dropbox for iOS app, but I'll be sure to pass this along as feedback.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26587543/dropbox-ios-targeting-files-with-url (says same thing).

Answer (score 0):

Have you gone through this tutorials link of DropBox https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/sdks/ios

[image]