# How to open Dropbox app from an another App in IOS Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am trying to open the dropbox App from my app. Here I can link and upload the files into the dropbox correctly. I have a link button to dropbox in my app, on clicking this I can be redirected to the dropbox app, I am using the code below.

```
if (!UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(NSUrl.FromString("testscheme://com.account.appname")))
{
NSString urlString = new NSString(Session.DropboxAPIHost);
NSUrl myFileUrl = new NSUrl(urlString);
UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(myFileUrl)
}
```

But nothing will happening. I am new to xamarin Please suggest a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use url scheme to open dropbox.
I tried it and it works ~

```
//dbapi-1 is Dropbox url scheme
NSUrl appurl = NSUrl.FromString("dbapi-1:");
UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(appurl);
```

And maybe you can see this 
[Does dropbox app on iOS has a URL scheme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406546/does-dropbox-app-on-ios-has-a-url-scheme)

Comment: `OpenUrl` is deprecated in iOS 10 http://useyourloaf.com/blog/openurl-deprecated-in-ios10/

Comment: Thanks.
Like @BytesGuy said.
OpenUrl is deprecated in iOS 10.
So ,If you want to use new method to replace OpenUrl.
you can see this:
https://annhanmovienight.wordpress.com/2017/01/11/xamarin-ios-openurl-is-deprecated-in-ios-10/